# CRUD WEB API with entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api

I started develop my project - web application with Database. I used WEB API with entity framework
I need CRUD operations realize in my project.

Read - work fine

But I don't know how realize Create, Update, Delete; I don't have enough experience and be glad yours advice.

I tried realize good architecture of my application - using repository pattern and fabric pattern. If you have advice in architecture of my project , I'll be grateful you.

I don't know how realize it in value controller and repository, could you help please?

Attach my code:

Repository

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI
{
    public class CustomerRepository
    {
        public IQueryable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
        {
            DevelopersEntities dev = new DevelopersEntities();
            return dev.Customers;
        }

        public IQueryable<Customer> GetAllCustomers(int id)
        {
            DevelopersEntities dev = new DevelopersEntities();
            return dev.Customers.Where(c=>c.Id==id).Select(e=>e);
        }

        public IQueryable<Customer> DeleteCustomer(int id)
        {
            DevelopersEntities dev = new DevelopersEntities();
            return dev.Customers.Remove(id);
        }

        public IQueryable<Customer> CreateCustomer()
        {
            DevelopersEntities dev = new DevelopersEntities();


        }

        public IQueryable<Customer> UpdateCustomer(int id)
        {
            DevelopersEntities dev = new DevelopersEntities();

        }
    }
}
```

Customer model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using WebAPI;

namespace DevelopersWeb.Models
{
    public class CustomerModel
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<HardwareModel> Hardware { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SoftwareModel> Software { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Harware Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace DevelopersWeb.Models
{
    public class HardwareModel
    {
        public int HardwareId { get; set; }
        public string HardwareName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Software Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace DevelopersWeb.Models
{
    public class SoftwareModel
    {
        public int SoftwareId { get; set; }
        public string SoftwareName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model Factory

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using WebAPI;

namespace DevelopersWeb.Models
{
    public class ModelFactory
    {
        public CustomerModel Create(Customer customer)
        {
            return new CustomerModel()
            {
                CustomerId = customer.Id,
                CustomerName = customer.Name,

                Hardware = customer.HardWares.Select(h=>Create(h)),
                Software = customer.Softwares.Select(c=>Create(c))
            };
        }

        public HardwareModel Create(HardWare hardware)
        {
            return new HardwareModel()
            {
                HardwareId = hardware.HardWareId,
                HardwareName = hardware.HardWareName,
            };
        }

        public SoftwareModel Create(Software software)
        {
            return new SoftwareModel()
            {
                SoftwareId = software.SoftwareId,
                SoftwareName = software.SoftwareName
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Value Controller

```
using DevelopersWeb.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebAPI;

namespace DevelopersWeb.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        ModelFactory _modelFactory;

        public ValuesController()
        {
            _modelFactory = new ModelFactory();
        }
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<CustomerModel> Get()
        {
            CustomerRepository cr = new CustomerRepository();
            return cr.GetAllCustomers().ToList().Select(c=> _modelFactory.Create(c));
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "xxx";
        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {

        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can read the documents from microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should save customer object:

```
public void CreateCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    DevelopersEntities dev = new DevelopersEntities();
    dev.Customers.Add(customer)
    dev.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here is you api action:

```
  // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]CustomerModel customerModel)
    {
       //Here you should transform CustomerModel object to customerEntity
        CustomerRepository cr = new CustomerRepository();
        cr.CreateCusomer(customer);

        return Ok();
    }
```

You should think about using Dependency Injection pattern here as well.

Comment: Why then you save customer object you doesn't use IQueryable<Customer>
I don't understand what does it mean - Here you should transform CustomerModel object to customerEntity
Could you tell me a bit more, please